# Macvim - CJK-specific font settings?

Tags: unicode, font, macvim

Currently in my MacVim, the English font (Source Code Pro Light) is fine, but the Chinese font is being rendered in a very ugly manner. Is there any way to specify what font to use/fontsize for CJK characters, in a similar way as one is able to do so in LaTeX? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it seems that I didn't Google enough... A quick Googling tells me that `set guifontwide` is the way to go(in the same way as `set guifont`)

Comment: Try the built-in `:help`, it is a very worthy alternative to google.

Comment: @romainl How do you use `:help` to get CJK font settings? I would like to know :)

Comment: `:help guifont` and scroll around.